# setTimeout does not work

Tags: javascript, settimeout, countdown

I'm very beginning with js and I have no idea why it doesn't countdown. Any tips? (it also doesn't work when I use `setInterval`).

When eventDate is a kind of any usual date like

```
var eventDate =new date (2016,12,25);
```

it works. 
The console does not show any mistakes.

```js
    
        function countdown() {
            var now = Date.parse(new Date);
            var eventDate = new Date(now + 1800000);
    
            var remTime = eventDate - now;
    
            var s = Math.floor(remTime / 1000);
            var m = Math.floor(s / 60);
    
            m %= 60;
            s %= 60;
    
            m = (m < 10) ? "0" + m : m;
            s = (s < 10) ? "0" + s : s;
    
            document.getElementById("minutes").textContent = m;
            document.getElementById("seconds").textContent = s;
    
            setTimeout("countdown()", 1000);
        }
    
        countdown();
```

```css
body {
                 background: #f6f6f6;
             }
    
             .countdownContainer {
                 position: absolute;
                 top: 50%;
                 left: 50%;
                 transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
                 text-align: center;
                 background: #ddd;
                 border: 1px solid #ddd;
                 padding: 10px;
                 box-shadow: 0 0 5px 3px #ccc;
             }
    
             .info {
                 font-size: 80px;
             }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <title>Christmas Countdown</title>
       
    </head>
    <body>
    <table class="countdownContainer">
        <tr class="info">
            <td colspan="4">Christmas Countdown</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="info">
            <td id="minutes">12</td>
            <td id="seconds">22</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Minutes</td>
            <td>Seconds</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Try `setTimeout(countdown, 1000);` if you want to read more then take a look at this http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp

Comment: That's cleaner, but doesn't make any difference.

Comment: It also doesn;t work that way. Thanks for the link but I have read it before.

Comment: Timeout is best for this as each time you run the function you will be adding a new interval so after 5 seconds you will have 5 intervals calling your countdown function.

Comment: @NewToJS: After 5 seconds you'd have 625 intervals running because the increase would be exponential. But then if you were using `setInterval`, you'd just remove the nested call and just call it from the outside so that there's only one ever running.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are couple of things wrong here one with code and second with logic of the function.

First of all you need to pass function in the setTimeout therefore it should be `setTimeout(countdown, 100);`

Secondly in the logic you are calculating

`var now = Date.parse(new Date);`

`var eventDate = new Date(now + 1800000);`

and then calculating deference of both which will result in the same value for each loop.

```js
var eventDate = new Date(Date.parse(new Date) + 1800000);

function countdown() {
  var now = Date.parse(new Date);


  var remTime = eventDate - now;

  var s = Math.floor(remTime / 1000);
  var m = Math.floor(s / 60);

  m %= 60;
  s %= 60;

  m = (m < 10) ? "0" + m : m;
  s = (s < 10) ? "0" + s : s;

  document.getElementById("minutes").innerHTML = m;
  document.getElementById("seconds").innerHTML = s;

  setTimeout(countdown, 1000);
}

countdown();
```

```css
body {
  background: #f6f6f6;
}
.countdownContainer {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
  text-align: center;
  background: #ddd;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  padding: 10px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px 3px #ccc;
}
.info {
  font-size: 80px;
}
```

```html
<table class="countdownContainer">
  <tr class="info">
    <td colspan="4">Christmas Countdown</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="info">
    <td id="minutes">12</td>
    <td id="seconds">22</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Minutes</td>
    <td>Seconds</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Why is the timeout set to 100ms when the time is only set to change every second? The function would run 10x before it's due to change...

Comment: @A.J No A.J you rushed to get the first answer posted. Then you edit the answer after adding detail. I have seen this many times.

Comment: @Karolina : Did you consider the two points mentioned? Run the snippet it is working her. Please share your observation of what is not working.

Comment: @A.J thank you ! It's now working ! It was definitely my mistake, I put eventDate into a function.